# What’s the grey altitude depicted in the profile view on Jeppesen charts?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, instrument-procedures, jeppesen

What’s the altitude depicted in grey in the profile view? Why there are some approaches that this isn’t depicted and some are?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The grey areas are the minimum descent altitude (MDA) for each approach segment. Below those altitudes there are hazards in those segments. When you conduct the approach you should be aware of those altitudes and take action if you get too close to them.

Comment: Might be worth to point out it even says MDA

Comment: @DeepSpace It only says MDA on the final segment because that is the approach MDA (which possibly depends on aircraft category, go-around performance, etc.) and can be found further below on the chart. The previous segments are not labelled MDA because they have a fixed minimum altitude (1250' and 850' in the example above).